# Comment traduire "game literacy" par exemple?

Tags: traduction

Bonjour,
J'aime discuter de beaucoup de choses et souvent je me retrouve contraint a utiliser le terme de "literacy" qui désigne l'habitude a certaines codifications et ou règles non écrites. par exemple si on parle de "design literacy" cela sous entend l'idée que pour fermer une fenêtre on clique sur la croix en haut a gauche, etc.

L'ennui est que alphabétisme me semble trop lié à la lecture/écriture pour être une traduction adaptée. Y a t-il une formulation existante en français quant à ce terme?

Comment: Do you mean game literacy or gaming literacy? Literacy ici veut dire, au fond, connaissances.

Comment: Like this?: Introduction: Literacy and games from the inside-out
Gaming literacy is an approach to literacy based on game design. https://s3.us-central-1.wasabisys.com/docdrop-annotations-prod/Zimmerman-Gaming-Literacy-tHZ5I.pdf?response-content-disposition=inline&response-content-type=application%2Fpdf&AWSAccessKeyId=AWCEUIGU61SBFN1TTFDK&Signature=iPG%2BnJLbj6TOWwS6ce6SRRjKEIs%3D&Expires=1637850848

Comment: connaissances (dans le domaine) des jeux: literacy= competence or knowledge in a specified area.

Comment: Ces gens-ci pourront le confirmer. [blague] https://gamingcampus.fr/concept.html#bloc__concept__fondateurs

Comment: On perd en précision face à *literacy* mais pour être compris, j'utiliserais probablement quelque chose comme : *Il faut un minimum d'expérience en interface utilisateur*

Comment: @jlliagre  You are talking about                                              [computer literacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_literacy), or possibly [digital literacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_literacy). "Design literacy" is about being able to understand and appreciate how objects fit in their environment, not necessarily from the user's point of view.  It is more commonly used by designers and architects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien entendu qu'il ne s'agit pas d'alphabétisme, mot qui désigne d'abord un [système d'écriture](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/alphab%C3%A9tisme)<sup>1</sup>, mais qu'as-tu contre le mot littératie utilisé en français  depuis la [fin du siècle dernier](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=litt%C3%A9ratie&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3) quand il désigne la capacité à comprendre les formes de codification du langage au sens large (textes mais aussi, cartes, graphiques, organigrammes, etc.)<sup>2</sup>. Le mot est très couramment utilisé dans les métiers de l'enseignement, en sociologie, etc. On parle de [littératie numérique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litt%C3%A9ratie_num%C3%A9rique), de [littératie informationnelle](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litt%C3%A9ratie_informationnelle), etc.

Bien qu'emprunté à l'anglais le mot n'est plus depuis longtemps considéré comme un anglicisme, du moins par ceux qui l'utilisent dans leur pratique professionnelle. Il est depuis plusieurs années dans les dictionnaires, ([Robert en ligne](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/litteratie), par exemple) et est [beaucoup plus utilisé](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lettrisme%2Clitt%C3%A9risme%2Clitt%C3%A9ratie&year_start=1930&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3) que les termes officiel de [lettrisme et littérisme](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=litt%C3%A9ratie&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) recommandés par France Terme.

La capacité a comprendre et s'approprier les règles d'un jeu vidéo rentre dans la littératie numérique. Pourquoi ne pas parler de la littératie ludique qui couvrirait toutes les sortes de jeu ? J'ai même déjà rencontré le terme de « [littératie vidéo ludique](http://psychologik.blogspot.com/2016/03/la-litteratie-video-ludique.html) ».

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Il n'y a que [l'UNESCO](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analphab%C3%A9tisme#D%C3%A9finition_de_l%27UNESCO) qui emploie alphabétisme comme antonyme d'analphabétisme.</sup>  
<sup><sup>2</sup> [Ici](https://www.oecd.org/fr/education/innovation-education/39438013.pdf) par exemple un rapport de l'OCDE sur la littératie datant de l'année 2000.</sup>